# Update Django Object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've an object:-

```
a = Model.objects.get(id=1)
```

and a dictionary of data attributes of object `a`.

```
update_data = {
colA: 1,
colB: 2,
colC: 3,
}
```

Now, I want to update object `a`. How can I do it?

Note:- `.update()` works on queryset, not on the object. Also, I cannot do `a.colA=1` because in that case, I've use `setattr` on each key.

Is there any way that I can update the object directly?

Comment: Where does the dictionary come from? You could probably use a form.

Comment: have you tried to filter with id and then apply update? i.e. `Model.objects.filter(id=1).update(**update_data)`

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I've a function which accepts the dictionary and the user object..

Comment: @Gahan - I know this, but the question is I've an object. How do I update it?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Where's the dict coming from? Is it being submitted by the user? In which case why don't you use a form?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast you can access if of object to filter too

Comment: Yes, initially the data is accepted via form itself and then the data is routed to some function.

Comment: But why don't you use the form to save the data?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - With due respect, you're being too chatty. This is how I've designed it and I know what I'm doing. The question is not `why`, the question is `how`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.update()` method like this:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=1).update(**update_data)
```

or you can update the individual object (iterating in `update_data` dict), too:

```
a = Model.objects.get(id=1)

for name in update_data:
    setattr(a, name, update_data[name])

# don't forget to save the object after modifying
a.save()
```

Comment: Great answer! But I want to know if there is a quicker way to do this? As we know, the for loop in python is pretty slow.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do

```
a = Model.object.get(id=1)
a.__dict__.update(update_data)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, Is it the standard way of doing it?

Comment: Absolutely No, Then why dont you use standard `setattr` ? You can loops over dict and use that

Comment: @itzMEonTV you need to save the instance too to commit changes in db

Answer (score 2):

For updating directly considering dictionary already constructed, you may filter objects first and then easily update the data, also `filter()` is faster then `get()` (*I have tested on small database size)

As you said in comment if you only have object (model instance) and dictionary you can write it as below:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=a.id).update(**update_data)
```

The performance result (tested on small db size)
    In [4]: g = Genres.objects.last()

```
In [6]: %timeit Genres.objects.get(id=g.id)
518 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit Genres.objects.filter(id=g.id)
74.2 µs ± 807 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```